# Cordova expansion file error: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: cordova, whitelist, expansion

I am using Cordova 5.3.1 and [this plugin](https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader/tree/cordova-5.3.1) to work with expansion files.
Here are other plugins i use in this project:
com.google.play.services 25.0.0 "Google Play Services for Android"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.5.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio 1.0.1 "background-audio"

My index.html has tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *  'unsafe-inline'; img-src * 'self'  data: cdvfile://* content://*;">`
My config.xml has 
    `<access origin="*" />
    <access origin="content:///*"/>
    <access origin="cdvfile:///*"/>
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*://*/*"/>`

I cant get media files from my expansion file. All it's sources start with content://com.my.expansion/ 
But i have error

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

pointing to image adress (content://com.my.expansion/image.jpg)

Can anyone say what am i doing wrong?